# psycopg2 cursor.execute not binding parameters

Tags: python, postgresql, string-formatting, psycopg2

Here's my code:

```
    with open(params['dataFile']) as df:

        conn = psycopg2.connect(params['connStr'])
        cur = conn.cursor()
        its = 0

        for line in df:
            if its == 0:
                pass
            else:
                row = tuple(line.replace('\n','').split(params['delimiter']))
                try:
                    cur.execute(params['insQueryStr'],row)
                except:
                    print(cur.mogrify(params['insQueryStr'],row))
                    print(row)
                    break

            its += 1

        conn.commit
        conn.close
```

Without the try/catch, it produces this:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO mstest values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %...
```

With the try catch, the call to mogrify prints this:

```
b'INSERT INTO mstest values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);'
```

The '%s's in my query string are not being replaced with the elements of the second parameter of the call to cur.execute(). Why? When row is printed, it contains the values I expect.

Comment: What is the output of `print (row)`?

Comment: ('8582665123456789', '0123456789', '1', '23.23.23.0', '2', '"AM_NA_United States_Commercial_Cloud & Enterprise_Starship"', '', '', '', '', '', '', '"FY12_FY12 Q2 Trial Layer _Vue_Sit_Trial_TY_FNL"', '', '', '1112345673742', 'Unknown','Unknown', '', '', '11123456772393', '', '', '11234567160', '"Starship - Empowering Media"', '', '', '', '', '1101234571181', '"AM_NA_United States_Commercial_Cloud & Enterprise_Starship"', '1112345155', '"Starship Corporation"', '', '', '', '', 'v3/gto.-1/bmw1.redefined/bmw2.redefined/atc3.3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','')

Answer (score 0):

From http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters :

For positional variables binding, the second argument must always be a sequence, even if it contains a single variable. And remember that Python requires a comma to create a single element tuple:
`

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", "bar")    # WRONG
cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ("bar"))  # WRONG
cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ("bar",)) # correct
cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ["bar"])  # correct
```

`

It might be what you are doing wrong feeding a tuple to cursor.execute()

Comment: I am inserting a sequence:

tuple(line.replace('\n','').split(params['delimiter']))

Comment: tuples have worked for me in past applications of cursor.execute()

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. I don't know why it does not. You say you modified the tuple a bit. Post the tuple exactly as it is, not a redacted version. Anyway the following is much simpler.

Since Psycopg adapts a Python tuple to a Postgresql record pass it as a single parameter:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO mstest values %s', (row,))
```

Notice the comma after `row`. It makes the `row` tuple the parameter itself.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for putting some thought into this. I can't post the sample row because it contains client data. I left all pertinent syntactic elements. I don't think the sample code would work. You see, row is itself a tuple, so (row,) is a tuple with one element - the tuple representing my row.

Comment: @duuug Updated. Do exactly as I posted and you will be surprised.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Continuum\Anaconda3\csv2pg\csv2pg.py", line 23, in <module>
    cur.execute(params['insQueryStr'],(row,))
psycopg2.DataError: value too long for type character varying(100)

Comment: So I have another script which runs, with a similar line like this: cur.execute("INSERT INTO bqTest values (%s, %s, %s, %s);",row) - why would the same thing not work in this instance?

Comment: @duuug What is the `mogrify` output? One of the columns has a maximum size of 100 and you tried to insert a bigger value.

Comment: @duuug You code should work as posted but there is something that is missing in the question. A major source of this kind of problem is to not declare the columns you are inserting into like in `insert into t (a,b) values (1,2)`